# Cannot install jupyter notebook

Tags: windows-7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In windows 7, I try to install jupyter notebook using:

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

But I get error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5in28fbw\pywinpty\
```

Answer (score 2):

Best thing to do is to install Anaconda [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos)

It includes its own "conda" terminal window for "windows", which will make it a lot easier for you to invoke jupiter notebook from the conda terminal, regardless of which folder you are in

Answer (score 1):

First update if using linux system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Restart the system and try below steps:
Installing Jupyter with pip
As an existing or experienced Python user, you may wish to install Jupyter using Python’s package manager, pip, instead of Anaconda.

If you have Python 3 installed (which is recommended):

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

If you have Python 2 installed:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip
sudo python -m pip install jupyter
```

Congratulations, you have installed Jupyter Notebook! To run the notebook, run the following command at the Terminal (Mac/Linux) or Command Prompt (Windows Run CMD in Admin):

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: There is no `sudo` and `apt-get` on Windows

Comment: Here is Ref: 1. https://jupyter.org/install, 2. https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 1):

Update your `setuptools` and `pip` first then retry:

```sh
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```