# How to install Jupyter notebook into a linux virtual machine

Tags: python, linux, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to install Jupyter notebook into a linux virtual machine. I've already gone through all the steps on various different sites but I keep running into different errors, and when I try to use the jupyter command, it says it "is not found", so the installations clearly didn't work. I've been getting errors when trying to use/update pip as well.

**What I've done so far:**

- Checked my Python version: I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.2 installed on the VM.
- I made sure pip was installed. It automatically installed version 8, so I updated it with this `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. It was working for a bit even though it kept saying there's a newer version available and I should upgrade. However now it just keps giving me the following error anytime I try to use pip for anything (even `pip --version` to see the version gives this error):

  ```
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
      sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                     ^
  ```
- Trying to upgrade pip with `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` gives me the following error:

  ```
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
      sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                     ^
  ```
- And trying to install jupyter with pip3 gives me a similar error:

  ```
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/home/vmadmin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
      sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                     ^
  ```

I've already tried the solutions from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849385/cannot-install-jupyter-notebook) that also had a different error I got previously, but they didn't work and I'm just really not sure where to look to solve these errors, so any pointers would be really helpful. My end goal is to get Jupyter notebook installed, configured, and up and running through a port on my Linux VM (Ubuntu 16.04.7).

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Yes, that alone didn't give me any errors, but when I restart my VM and retry updating pip and installing jupyter, I still get the same errors @JeongKim

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is an unsupported syntax. Both Python 2.7 and 3.5 have no longer support by Pip. Newer pip versions introduced string formatting on its code (f-strings):

```py
s = f"Hello, {your_name}"
```

But this feature was introduced in Python 3.6, that's why everything failed for you. So you should upgrade your Python version.